# Why is Thin my default Rails server now? I didn't even know about it before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin, webrick

Since a little while, when starting up Rails server using `rails s`, Webrick isn't started anymore, but Thin is. Strangely, I didn't even hear about Thin before, so I wonder where it is coming from?

I seem to have the `thin` gem installed on my machine, maybe it was a dependency? In my `Gemfile`, there is no Thin listed.

Any idea how Thin sneaked into my application? I'm using Rails 3.2. Thank you.

Comment: I think Thin has been the default webserver for a few versions now. At least for me since doing Rails 3.2 i've always noticed thin being started as default webserver.
But don't worry. Thin is better than Webrick (at least from what I've heard)